How can I use a custom useFetch composable in a Pinia action?
I am using Vue3 + Nuxt3. My backend API is a separate NestJS project on a separate URL that will also change within environments. Because of this it is best for me to have a custom useFetch composable whenever I am interacting with my API. It works and I have followed the docs in order to do it: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/recipes/custom-usefetch#custom-usefetchuseasyncdata
The problem is that when I try to use this composable in a pinia action, I get a warning:
enter image description here
This is how I am calling my composable in the pinia store:
const {data, error} = await useAPI('/auth/login', { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify({email, password}) });
It works but I am aware that using composables outside of setup is not correct and in this case I should use $fetch directly. However, the custom composable is specifically to make calling my API a lot easier, I need to be able to use it in event handlers. Can anybody point me in the right direction please? I've looked everywhere.
I have tried to incorporate the same utility into $fetch but I cannot achieve it.

"I have tried to incorporate" - what did you try? The question needs to be specific. " I need to be able to use it in event handlers" - if you have existing code, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Generally the answer is is "in no way". useFetch isn't a glorified fetch, it's a composable. It's supposed to run where it's allowed, i.e. nuxt hooks and components. Which a store isn't. A safe workaround is to do store.fetchResult = useFetch(..) or similar in root comp and then use fetchResult in a store. It's unknown which useFetch features you're missing when you use $fetch

@EstusFlask Thanks for your reply. The utility I want to incorporate into $fetch is to be able to flag the request as being for the 'api' so that the call can remain agnostic to the base url of the api. For example, on my local machine, I would want to call http://localhost:3001/auth/login but in production I may want to call https://api.foo.com/production/auth/login. I want to write all of my API calls to just 'auth/login' and have the base url resolved at runtime from the environment.

You can supply baseURL to $fetch.create, this is how it differs from vanilla fetch.
